# Enemy Spawning Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sprite

I am making an android game that spawns enemy sprites at a certain interval at the top of the screen. There are no syntax errors, but when I run the game it crashes because of this function:

```
public void updateEnemies() {
    if (numEnemiesCreated == numVisibleEnemies) {
        if (timeLastCreatedEnemy + 1000 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            timeLastCreatedEnemy = System.currentTimeMillis();
            boolean createdNewEnemy = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.numVisibleEnemies; i++) {
                if (createdNewEnemy == false) {
                    if (holderEnemy[i].isDisposed()) {
                        this.generateNewEnemy(i);
                        createdNewEnemy = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<numVisibleEnemies; i++){
            if(!holderEnemy[i].isDisposed()){
                holderEnemy[i].move();
            }
        }
    } else {
        holderEnemy[numEnemiesCreated] = new Enemy(context, 0, 0);
        numEnemiesCreated++;
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, I just can't get it to work!  Here is my log cat crash report:

```
05-25 18:49:13.031: W/dalvikvm(6736): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
05-25 18:49:13.035: E/AndroidRuntime(6736): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
05-25 18:49:13.035: E/AndroidRuntime(6736): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 18:49:13.035: E/AndroidRuntime(6736):     at com.jlennon.gametest.EnemySpawn.updateEnemies(EnemySpawn.java:49)
05-25 18:49:13.035: E/AndroidRuntime(6736):     at com.jlennon.gametest.MainGamePanel$AnimationThread.update(MainGamePanel.java:94)
05-25 18:49:13.035: E/AndroidRuntime(6736):     at com.jlennon.gametest.MainGamePanel$AnimationThread.run(MainGamePanel.java:61)
```

Comment: Care to tell us what's line 49 there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the uncaught exception you're getting is a `NullPointerException`, you will need to check that every element inside of `holderEnemy` is instantiated to its proper type.  You can't dereference `null` - which is what is given by default in an array.

To belabor the point a bit, if you take an array of elements such as:

```
Enemy[] holderEnemy = new Enemy[1000];
```

that is not enough to instantiate the array.  You will need to loop over the array and create new `Enemy`s for each element.  Otherwise, you'll need to guarantee that, within the bounds of [0, `numVisibleEnemies`), your array elements are properly instantiated.

(Note that I'm guessing at the object type, but the principle applies.)